# Excel Formula LET function based on Criteria

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, let

Self-Learning Excel, Im new with the LET function and i am Looking for a fix to the below formula, where B5144 is user input for Date in which the LET function will create a table based on user input in B5144 (Filter records where date values are matching with B5144).

Either using an IF/ Filter function as validation before generating a result. Where only records in the table that match the date value in B5144 will be displayed.

```
=SORT((LET(x,UNIQUE(D2:D5140),y,SUMIFS(J2:J5140,D2:D5140,x),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what output you are expecting from the formula and also what the current result is?

Consider using more descriptive names for your variables - the formulas are more self-documented in that case.

Comment: You do not use `B5144` in your formula.

Comment: Sorry, More like i need to use an IF function as validation before generating a result. Where only records in the table that match the date value in B5144 will be displayed.

Comment: Can you show us your expected output, and the data instead of a screenshot paste a textual copy able data

Comment: `A` returns a value for each row, while `x` and `y` return less. Can you explain what it is you expect to be calculated?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a dynamic array (filter) you are going to have to start with the filter and work your way out:

FILTER(A2:J5140,A2:A5140=B5144)

Once you have this "sub array" it is the only thing you will use, you will make no further references to A:xxx or J:xxx.

```
LET(results,FILTER(A2:J5140,A2:A5140=B5144),
A, index(results,,1),
x, index(results,,4),
y, index(results,,10)   )
```

And then move on from there.

results is a variable height x 10 column width array.

A, x, and Y are the same variable height x 1 column width array.

I believe your "unique" function is going to create a hot mess unless you are really clear in your logic.  Array "x" will often be shorter in length than A and y, and this may or may not be what you want.

You may have to nest Filters:  =Filter( Filter( xx by date ) by unique D )

In this way, you always end up with a matched A, x, and y array.

Hope this helps get you in the right direction.  Let us know if you need more.
———-
Edit: I only recently came to overflow from stackexchange so I don’t have enough points to make comments yet, so I’ll respond here.

My formula above just does the filter and sets the definitions, are you then entering your desired formula at the end just inside the final parenthesis?

Comment: Im getting a single cell with value "0"